# Is it possible to extend desktop with mission control spaces (no dock, icons, menubar on second or third space)?

Tags: catalina, dock, menu-bar, spaces, mission-control

I googled and didn't find anything, I know changing wallpapers is allowed for different spaces, on a single macbook is it possible to have the second and other spaces be different from the first like an extended display? Like having no dock and no menu bar and no icons while the first main space has all of that?

Comment: Disable "Displays have separate Spaces" In system prefs > Mission Control… but that may not be what you actually want. That will set one Space to be all screens at once, only one of which is Primary. I don't think there is any half-way house on that.

Comment: Oh… if you mean with only a single display… no.

Comment: yeah single display, looks like it's not possible, thanks.